# Can I somehow pass TInput/TOutput pages to a function as one parameter in Inno Setup?

Tags: parameters, inno-setup

I wonder if I can somehow pass `TInputQueryWizardPage`, `TInputOptionWizardPage`, `TInputDirWizardPage`, `TInputFileWizardPage`, `TOutputMsgWizardPage`, `TOutputMsgMemoWizardPage`, `TOutputProgressWizardPage` pages to a function as one parameter?

The reason I need this is because depending on the situation I have to pass one of those pages to a function that has the `case` statement inside that decides what changes must be done to a particular page and I don't want to pass 7 parameters.

Here's an example:

```
procedure SetPropertiesForPages(InputOptionWP: TInputOptionWizardPage; TextWP: TOutputMsgWizardPage; SelectDirWP: TInputDirWizardPage; InputQueryWP: TInputQueryWizardPage; Mode: String; AWordWrap: Boolean; AWidth, AHeight, ALeft, ATop: Integer);
begin
  case Lowercase(Mode) of
    'text':
      begin
         biLeftSideImage := CreateBitmapImage(TextWP, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\LefthandsideImg.bmp'), True, 0, 0);
         with TextWP do
           begin
             MsgLabel.WordWrap := AWordWrap;
             MsgLabel.Width := AWidth;
             MsgLabel.Height := AHeight;
             MsgLabel.Left := ALeft;
           end;   
      end;
    'inputoption1':
      begin
        biLeftSideImage := CreateBitmapImage(InputOptionWP, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\LefthandsideImg.bmp'), True, 0, 0);
        with InputOptionWP do
           begin
             SubCaptionLabel.WordWrap := AWordWrap;
             SubCaptionLabel.Width := AWidth;
             SubCaptionLabel.Left := ALeft;
             SubCaptionLabel.Top := ATop;
             CheckListBox.Width := AWidth;
             CheckListBox.Height := AHeight;
             CheckListBox.Left := ALeft;
             CheckListBox.Top := ATop + SubCaptionLabel.Height + ScaleY(20);
           end;   
      end;
    'inputoption2':
      begin
        biLeftSideImage := CreateBitmapImage(InputOptionWP, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\LefthandsideImg.bmp'), True, 0, 0);
        with InputOptionWP do
          begin
            SubCaptionLabel.WordWrap := AWordWrap;
            SubCaptionLabel.Width := AWidth;
            SubCaptionLabel.Height := 6 * AHeight + ScaleY(5);
            SubCaptionLabel.Left := ALeft;
            SubCaptionLabel.Top := ATop;
            CheckListBox.Width := AWidth;
            CheckListBox.Height := AHeight + ScaleY(40);
            CheckListBox.Left := ALeft;
            CheckListBox.Top := ATop + SubCaptionLabel.Height + ScaleY(5);  
          end; 
      end;
    'selectdir':
      begin
        biLeftSideImage := CreateBitmapImage(SelectDirWP, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\LefthandsideImg.bmp'), True, 0, 0);
        with SelectDirWP do
          begin
            Edits[0].ReadOnly := True;
            Edits[1].ReadOnly := True;
            Edits[0].Left := ALeft;
            Edits[1].Left := ALeft;
            Edits[0].Width := AWidth - ScaleX(70);
            Edits[1].Width := AWidth - ScaleX(70);
            Buttons[0].Left := Edits[0].Left + Edits[0].Width + ScaleX(10);
            Buttons[1].Left := Edits[1].Left + Edits[1].Width + ScaleX(10);
            PromptLabels[0].Left := ALeft;
            PromptLabels[1].Left := ALeft;
            SubCaptionLabel.WordWrap := AWordWrap;
            SubCaptionLabel.Width := AWidth;
            SubCaptionLabel.Left := ALeft;
            SubCaptionLabel.Top := ATop;
          end;
      end;
    'inputquery':
      begin
        biLeftSideImage := CreateBitmapImage(InputQueryWP, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\LefthandsideImg.bmp'), True, 0, 0);
        with InputQueryWP do
          begin
            Edits[0].Left := ALeft;
            Edits[0].Width := AWidth - ScaleX(75);
            PromptLabels[0].Left := ALeft;
            SubCaptionLabel.WordWrap := AWordWrap;
            SubCaptionLabel.Width := AWidth;
            SubCaptionLabel.Height := AHeight;
            SubCaptionLabel.Left := ALeft;
            SubCaptionLabel.Top := ATop;
          end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

So, as you can I seen I need to change different things for different types of pages, but I don't want to pass so many parameters.

Comment: What will the function do?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I've added an example.

Comment: Why do you even want to put all this into one function? There's hardly any common code. Create a separate function with only one page parameter for each page type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to operate over any of those pages, if must use only their common API/functionality. Their common API/functionality is their base class, the [`TWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardPage):

```pascal
procedure DoSomethingWithAnyCustomPage(WizardPage: TWizardPage);
begin
  // ...
end;
```

---

If many cases you can also implement the common functionality by using the same/shared implementation of pages events.